# postgres json_agg() ignores index in joined tables in GROUP BY expressions

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-optimization, aggregate-functions

I have two tables (foreign keys are omitted for simplicity):

```
CREATE TABLE timetables (
"ttid" SERIAL4 NOT NULL,
"bioid" int4 NOT NULL,
"component" int4,
"route" int2,
"time_num" numeric,
"time_unit" char(1) COLLATE "default",
"time_shift" int2,
"time_devstage" int2,
"times_total" int2,
"every_num" numeric,
"every_unit" char(1) COLLATE "default",
"duration_num" numeric,
"duration_unit" char(1) COLLATE "default",
"doseid" int4 NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "timetables_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("ttid"),
CONSTRAINT "timetables_doseid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("doseid") REFERENCES doses(doseid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
CREATE INDEX "timetables_bioid_idx" ON "timetables" USING btree (bioid);
CREATE INDEX "timetables_doseid_idx" ON "timetables" USING btree (doseid);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE doses (
"doseid" SERIAL4 NOT NULL,
"ai" numeric,
"conc" numeric,
"conc_unit" varchar COLLATE "default",
"vol" numeric,
"vol_unit" varchar COLLATE "default",
"amount" numeric,
"amount_unit" varchar COLLATE "default",
"area" numeric,
"area_unit" varchar COLLATE "default",
"numplants" numeric,
CONSTRAINT "doses_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("doseid")
);
```

The following query fails to use the index on "bioid" column:

```
SELECT bioid, json_agg (doses) jtd
FROM timetables
LEFT JOIN doses USING (doseid)
GROUP BY bioid
```

EXPLAIN returns the following:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=391.88..440.10 rows=2251 width=75)
  ->  Sort  (cost=391.88..398.57 rows=2677 width=75)
        Sort Key: timetables.bioid
        ->  Merge Right Join  (cost=0.56..239.47 rows=2677 width=75)
              Merge Cond: (doses.doseid = timetables.doseid)
              ->  Index Scan using doses_pkey on doses  (cost=0.28..93.79 rows=2367 width=75)
              ->  Index Scan using timetables_doseid_idx on timetables  (cost=0.28..106.43 rows=2677 width=8)
```

So, the SORT is explicitly made in spite of the key "timetables.bioid" is declared as an index.
If I will aggregate the "timetables" table instead of "doses" then the query became very fast:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=0.28..147.96 rows=2251 width=77)
  ->  Index Scan using timetables_bioid_idx on timetables  (cost=0.28..106.43 rows=2677 width=77)
```

How should I optimize the query to use indices or what indices should I add? Actually I need json_agg() of the whole output:
SELECT bioid, json_agg (td) jtd
FROM (timetables LEFT JOIN doses USING (doseid)) td
GROUP BY bioid

I am using Postgres 9.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But the query *does* use indexes, it just doesn't use the index you expect.

PostgreSQL estimates that it gets away cheapest by using a merge join. For that, the data in both tables must be sorted by the join condition, which is done using the indexes `doses_pkey` and `timetables_doseid_idx`.
After the join, the entries are sorted by `doseid`, so they have to be sorted again by `bioid` for the `GROUP BY` clause. An index cannot be used for that, since it is not a table but a join result that is sorted.

I think there is nothing to worry.

If you think that PostgreSQL is not using the right join method, you could try to `SET enable_mergejoin=off` and compare the plan that is generated then. Use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` to see if the optimizer estimated correctly; bad planner choices are usually caused by misestimates.

Comment: Disabling mergejoin almost does not affect the final cost.
Is it possible to sort the join result using indexes?

Comment: It is not about the cost, you should compare the actual runtime. As I said, you can't sort a join result with an index. How should that work?